# Q: How to export the Azure Service Log to the local storage of the VMs?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-automation

I'm very new to Azure.

I have several logs recorded and exported to the Azure Portal.

Is it possible to export those log into the Virtual Machine (An Instance) with using Automation Runbook?